# Getting values from util:list using ElementTree in Python 2.7.15

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, elementtree, xml.etree

I am using etree on python 2.7.15, and I stuck, I trying to parse XML File to get values from it.As you can see my code below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

def XMLParse(filename):
   filename = filename
   tree = etree.parse(filename)
   beans = tree.findall('{http://www.speedframework.org/schema/beans}bean')

   for bean in beans:
     for property in bean:

        if "name" in property.attrib and "value" in property.attrib:
            print ("This one catches PROP1:" + property.attrib['name'])
            print property.attrib

        if "name" in property.attrib and not "value" in property.attrib:
            for util in property.iter():
                for lists in util:
                    for parameter in lists:


                        if 'key' in parameter.attrib:
                            print ("This one catches PROP3:" + parameter.attrib['key'])

                        if 'bean' in parameter.attrib:
                            print ("This one catches PROP4:" + parameter.attrib['bean'])

                        if 'value' in parameter.attrib:
                            print ("This one should catch PROP2:" + parameter.attrib['value'])
                        print parameter.attrib


filename = open('static/test1.xml')
XMLParse(filename)
```

And here's my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.speedframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core" 
xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
xmlns:test="http://apache.org/hello_world_soap_http" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:util="http://www.speedframework.org/schema/util" 
xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security"
xmlns:context="http://www.speedframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://cxf.apache.org/core
http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
http://www.speedframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.speedframework.org/schema/beans/speed-beans-2.0.xsd
http://www.speedframework.org/schema/context
http://www.speedframework.org/schema/context/speed-context-3.0.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
http://www.speedframework.org/schema/util
http://www.speedframework.org/schema/util/speed-util-2.0.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration
http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security
http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/security.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:realm.properties"/>

<bean id="FOO" class="BAR">
    <property name="Prop1" value="ValueProp1" />
    <property name="Prop2">
        <util:list>
            <value>PropValue2A</value>
            <value>PropValue2B</value>
        </util:list>
    </property>
    <property name="Prop3">
        <util:map>
            <entry key="Prop3Key" value-ref="Prop3Value" />
        </util:map>
    </property>
    <property name="Prop4">
        <util:list>
            <ref bean="Prop4" />
        </util:list>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

As you can see prop1,prop3 and prop 4 are parsing fine.The problem is with **prop2**, when I try to get property.attrib all i got is just **{} {}** two empty brackets.My real xml is much much bigger that's why i am using loops. But also maybe there is better solution i was thinking about using xpath maybe?

OUTPUT:

```
This one catches PROP1:Prop1
{'name': 'Prop1', 'value': 'ValueProp1'}
{}
{}
This one catches PROP3:Prop3Key
{'value-ref': 'Prop3Value', 'key': 'Prop3Key'}
This one catches PROP4:Prop4
{'bean': 'Prop4'}
```

**MAJOR QUESTION:** How to get all "prop2" from util:list?

Comment: The last two lines of your code are strangely indented. Is that intentional? In any case, if I unindent those lines and run your code, I get `xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 47, column 7`. This doesn't seem to match up with the output you're getting. Can you double-check to confirm that you're running this code on this input and getting this output?

Comment: Oh, never mind. The final `</beans>` tag wasn't being rendered in the post. If I add that, I get the same output as you.

Comment: Last two lines were unintentional for sure my bad while copying, but the xml code works fine even when I have copy pasted it from here.

Comment: Right, because I edited the `</beans>` back in a minute ago :-)

Comment: Yup, my bad! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if 'value' in parameter.attrib:
```

This doesn't look right to me. Suppose `parameter` refers to the `<value>PropValue2A</value>` element. That  tag is a value element, but it does not have a value attribute. If it did, it would look like:

```
<value value=whatever>PropValue2A</value>
```

I think you want to check the element's name in this case, not its attributes.

```
for parameter in lists:


    if 'key' in parameter.attrib:
        print ("This one catches PROP3:" + parameter.attrib['key'])

    if 'bean' in parameter.attrib:
        print ("This one catches PROP4:" + parameter.attrib['bean'])

    if 'value' in parameter.tag:
        print ("This one should catch PROP2:" + parameter.tag)
    print parameter.attrib
```

Now your third conditional will pass twice while iterating over Prop2:

```
This one catches PROP1:Prop1
{'name': 'Prop1', 'value': 'ValueProp1'}
This one should catch PROP2:{http://www.speedframework.org/schema/beans}value
{}
This one should catch PROP2:{http://www.speedframework.org/schema/beans}value
{}
This one catches PROP3:Prop3Key
{'value-ref': 'Prop3Value', 'key': 'Prop3Key'}
This one catches PROP4:Prop4
{'bean': 'Prop4'}
```

Additionally, I think you've got one too many for loops in your code. You have five for loops, but the contents of your beans element only has a maximum tag depth of four. You get sensible output anyway because `property.iter` iterates over all nodes belonging to the property's tree, including itself, so that loop effectively cancels out in some cases. But you can simplify things by iterating over just the direct descendants of `property`, and skipping one of the loops.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

def XMLParse(filename):
   filename = filename
   tree = etree.parse(filename)
   beans = tree.findall('{http://www.speedframework.org/schema/beans}bean')

   for bean in beans:
     for property in bean:

        if "name" in property.attrib and "value" in property.attrib:
            print ("This one catches PROP1:" + property.attrib['name'])
            print property.attrib

        if "name" in property.attrib and not "value" in property.attrib:
            for util in property:
                for parameter in util:
                    if 'key' in parameter.attrib:
                        print ("This one catches PROP3:" + parameter.attrib['key'])

                    if 'bean' in parameter.attrib:
                        print ("This one catches PROP4:" + parameter.attrib['bean'])

                    if 'value' in parameter.tag:
                        print ("This one should catch PROP2:" + parameter.tag)
                    print parameter.attrib


filename = open('data.xml')
XMLParse(filename)
```

You should still get the same output, and it will be a bit faster.

```
This one catches PROP1:Prop1
{'name': 'Prop1', 'value': 'ValueProp1'}
This one should catch PROP2:{http://www.speedframework.org/schema/beans}value
{}
This one should catch PROP2:{http://www.speedframework.org/schema/beans}value
{}
This one catches PROP3:Prop3Key
{'value-ref': 'Prop3Value', 'key': 'Prop3Key'}
This one catches PROP4:Prop4
{'bean': 'Prop4'}
```

Comment: I have checked that but it gives back tag instead of content as you can see "http://www.speedframework.org/schema/beans}value" instead of PropValue2A and PropValue2B. Which I need to get. I dont have inpact on how data is given to me that's why i can''t change that to "value=" idea :(

Comment: If you want `PropValue2A`, then you just need to access it from the property's text attribute: `print ("This one should catch PROP2:" + parameter.text)`

Comment: So obvious! Thanks a lot!